# FormData do not send complete files in the server

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I am trying to upload multiple files to my server using jquery ajax.

So this is what i've done so far:

```
<input type="file" id="lab" name="lab[]" size="10" class="filestyle" multiple/>
```

This is my javascript that handle the change event :

```
 function on_documents_changed(){
        $("#lab").change(function() {
            var formdata = new FormData();

            //formdata.append('case_id', $('#case-id').text());
            var inp = document.getElementById('lab').files;

            for (var i = 1; i <= inp.length; i++) {
                formdata.append('lab_' + i, inp.item(i));
                console.log('Appended ' + i);
            }

            Main.Mod.do_ajax('casereport/upload_documents/laboratory', 'POST', function(){}, formdata);
        });
    }
```

This is the code for do_ajax;

```
function do_ajax(url,type,callback_function,formdata){
        var params = {
            type: type,
            url: Main.Vars.host + url,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,   
            processData:false, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                callback_function(data);
            }
        }
        if(formdata != null){
            params.data = formdata;
        }
        $.ajax(params);
    }
```

My problem here is, when I tried to upload, lets say, 4 files. It only read 3 files in the server. I noticed that only the last file was not read or maybe not even in $_FILES.

Your responses are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your for loop as `inp` is an array you it starts from index `0` but you are accessing it by 1 so first file will be skiped:-

```
 function on_documents_changed(){
    $("#lab").change(function() {
        var formdata = new FormData();

        //formdata.append('case_id', $('#case-id').text());
        var inp = document.getElementById('lab').files;

        for (var i = 0; i <  inp.length; i++) {
            formdata.append('lab_' + i, inp.item(i));
            console.log('Appended ' + i);
        }

        Main.Mod.do_ajax('casereport/upload_documents/laboratory', 'POST', function(){}, formdata);
    });
}
```

Comment: would you mind to share how the hell that works? I mean my loop also loops four times. Your answer is correct and will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @JCFrane first file exists  on index `0` but when you set `i=1` at this time your first loop will access second element which is on index `1`  and in last loop your last item will be null remember array index starts from `0` not from 1